# Not in clause not filtering SQL Server with open query

Tags: sql-server, informix, notin

So I have two tables that look like this

---

Inventory table (this is just pulling a list of empty locations)

```
|loc|

|ECA001|
_____
```

Inventory Transfer Job List table

```
|id | oid | sku | from_loc | to_loc | tag | qty | processed |  create_date | processed date

|2  | 003 | 123 | SD034 |  |T100010| 2 | NULL | 2017-04-06 | NULL

___
```

What I want to do is populate the Inventory_Transfer_Job_List_Table. To_loc with the next empty location on my first table & location not already used in my Inventory_Transfer_Job_List.to_loc table

I'm just working a select statement now to make sure before I update that I'm inserting the right data.

I tried

```
select * from
    (select loc from openquery(wms7,'SELECT lc_f.loc FROM lc_f left join iv_f on 
    lc_f.loc = iv_f.loc WHERE lc_f.loc like ''EC%'' AND lc_f.loc not in   (select 
    loc from iv_f where loc like ''EC%'' OR loc = ''ECRETURNS'')')) as a , 
[db1].[dbo].[ECOM_Transfer_Inventory_Job_List]  as b
where to_loc = ''
and a.loc  not in (SELECT to_loc
               FROM   [db1].[dbo].[ECOM_Transfer_Inventory_Job_List] 
               WHERE  to_loc != '')
```

but I'm only getting a repeated value

```
ex.
loc | id | oid | sku | from_loc | to_loc | tag | qty | processed |  create_date | processed date

|ECA001| 1 | 0001 |0003 | MCA022 | | T100001| 2 | Null | 2017-04-06 | NULL

|ECA001| 7 | 0023 |0015 | MCA049 | | T100051| 12 | Null | 2017-04-06 | NULL
```

instead of it just filtering out the ones that have already been used.

Help help would be great thank you,

Comment: You're doing a `CROSS JOIN`. So you're going to get the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: SQL-Server or Informix, not the same thing...

Comment: I'm building it on sql-server but the openquery is informix

Comment: Thank you bjones, I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what your query is doing.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 a
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 2) a,
(SELECT 3 b
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 4) b
```

Try adding `WHERE Something in table a = something in table b`.

Or `ON a.Column = b.Column`

If you have SQL-Server 2008 + perhaps something like the following will suit your needs.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY loc) AS RowNum, loc 
 FROM OPENQUERY(wms7,'SELECT lc_f.loc FROM lc_f LEFT JOIN iv_f ON 
lc_f.loc = iv_f.loc WHERE lc_f.loc LIKE ''EC%'' AND lc_f.loc NOT IN (SELECT 
loc FROM iv_f WHERE loc LIKE ''EC%'' OR loc = ''ECRETURNS'')')) AS a
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum, *
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[ECOM_Transfer_Inventory_Job_List])  AS b ON  a.RowNum = b.RowNum
WHERE b.to_loc = ''
  AND a.loc  NOT IN (SELECT to_loc
                     FROM   [db1].[dbo].[ECOM_Transfer_Inventory_Job_List] 
                     WHERE  to_loc != '')
```

Comment: Thank you, but how should I join them if they don't have any common columns to match?

Comment: @CharlesCooper , You may need to make a decision based on business requirements, but maybe the above edited will help.

Comment: You're the man! Thank you for teaching me about the cartesian product.

Comment: @CharlesCooper , glad I could help.